# JAVA Exception in main thread java.lang.NoDefFounderror: net/........./AbstractClock

Tags: java, exception, command-line, noclassdeffounderror

I have a clock program as `AbstractClock.java` in `C:\Users\Neeraj\Prg folder`.

CLASSPATH is specified as `C:\Users\Neeraj\Prg`

COMPILED `javac AbstractClock.java` with no errors.

RUN AS   `java -cp . net.sf.fmj.ejmf.toolkit.media.AbstractClock`

Getting errors as

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/fmj/ejmf/toolkit/media/AbstractClock
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net/sf/fmj/ejmf/toolkit/media/AbstractClock
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:315)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
Could not find the main class: com.hib.TranslateSQL.  Program will exit.
```

PROGRAM:-

```
package net.sf.fmj.ejmf.toolkit.media;

import java.lang.*;
import javax.media.Clock;
import javax.media.Time;

import javax.media.TimeBase;

public class AbstractClock implements Clock {

    private TimeBase systemtimebase = Manager.getSystemTimeBase();

    public AbstractClock() { super(); }

    ///REST ALL METHODS
}
```

I am running this in commandprompt in Windows. I have seen other posts and changed classpath and run command, but still error occurs.Please provide steps suitable for running in windows in command prompt  to rectify this mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Is you java file in C:\Users\Neeraj\Prg or is it in C:\Users\Neeraj\Prg\net\sf\fmj\ejmf\toolkit\media\ ? 
Packages in java are related to directories. So your classpath is the top level directory in which packages live. A class with the package name net.sf.fmj.ejmf.toolkit should be in that directory.